# Intuitive Explanation behind algebraically adding the vertical shifts produced by transparent objects

Tags: visible-light, speed-of-light, refraction, geometric-optics

[image]

Given are two transparent slabs of different refractive indexes, a point object is placed at the bottom of $B$. My book says that the total shift produced is the algebraic sum of the shifts of each slab, but can someone intuitively explain it, without much mathematical formulae?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of the slabs as two different objects which "push" the image up or down.

Think the object was initially placed just below $A$, and $B$ is not there. The shift can be calculated using the formulae $D_a=D_r(1-\frac{1}{\mu})$, but since you dont want to get into formulae as of yet, consider my "pushing" analogy.

So, when $A$ is the only slab, then the shift produced by it pushes the image down. Now if another slab $B$ is slipped in between the point object and $A$, it "teams up" with the other slab and together help in pushing the object down, and the shift of the image will be the total amount by which the slabs have pushed it down.

Now if some slab is added with refractive index lesser than the medium of the observer, then it tries to push the image "up" by some amount($D_r(1-\frac{1}{\mu})$, which is going to be a negative value here), and the total shift produced will be adding the "negative value of shift"(i.e., the shift upwards) with the shift downwards produced by the slabs, somewhat like a "net shift" produced.